# APNS: sending Push notifications every minute. Should this cause issues?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I read that when sending notifications to APNS, all messages should be sent together in one connection, and that we should avoid disconnecting from the server for each message. I would like to know if reconnecting every a minute or so might pose a problem?

From [Best Practices for Managing Connections](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW8):

> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; 
>   don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid
>   connection and  disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You
>   should leave a connection  open unless you know it will be idle for an
>   extended period of time—for  example, if you only send notifications
>   to your users once a day it is ok to  use a new connection each day.

Comment: you actually send every minute or you AVG is a message a minute?

Comment: multiple messages, but reconnecting every minute or so